# How to detect a click inside an iframe and make the original page react to that click

Tags: iframe

So basically i want to embed a form from one page(daughter) inside a different page(parent) and when people click the submit button in that form 2 things happen:1. the details are saved to the owner of the page(daughter) 2. the parent page gets redirect to another page.

is that possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.